# CakePHP: Form helper with saveMany() to edit multiple rows at once

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

In my view (/View/Tests/admin_edit.ctp) I want to edit multiple rows (from a different model) by pointing the form to the QsetsController and the "admin_order" action then use the `saveMany($this->request->data)` to update all changes.

**/View/Tests/admin_edit.ctp:**

```
echo $this->Form->create( 'Qset', array('action'=>'order', 'admin'=>1));
$n = 1;
foreach ($qsets as $qset) : ?>
        <h3>Question set <?php echo $n; $n++;?></h3>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('Qset.'.$n.'.order'); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('Qset.'.$n.'.id', array('type'=>'hidden') ); ?>
        ...
        $n++;

    endforeach;

echo $this->Form->end('save');
```

**/Controller/QsetsController.php**

```
public function admin_order() {

    $data = $this->request->data; //maybe just $this->data ?

    $this->Qset->saveAll($data);
    $this->Session->setFlash( "Order saved.");
    $this->redirect( Controller::referer() );
}
```

Currently, my data does not get saved (although there are no errors).
Also, only the *first* input echoed by the foreach loop appears with a correct `order` field value. Each subsequent one has no value at all.

**Update:**
I changed `$n = 1` to `$n = 0` and now the first *AND* second input appear with their correct order values.

**update2:**
The markup for the form starts like this:

```
<form action="/admin/qsets/order" id="QsetOrderForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

The markup for the input fields which appear correct:

```
<div class="input number"><label for="Qset2Order">Order</label>
<input name="data[Qset][2][order]" type="number" value="3" id="Qset2Order">
</div>
```

The markup that results for the empty input fields:

```
<div class="input number"><label for="Qset3Order">Order</label>
<input name="data[Qset][3][order]" type="number" id="Qset3Order">
</div>
```

**Update3:**
I solved the problem with the inputs not displaying correctly! Notice I was incrementing `$n` *before* echoing the the inputs, so this was creating duplicates at the end of the loop. I moved `$n++` to after the inputs and now they appear correctly. Phew. Now I just need to get them to save.

Useful references:
[Cake book chapter on saveMany()/saveAll()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html)
[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797151/edit-multiple-rows-with-one-form-in-cake)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You reference the manual but probably haven't read it well enough :)

Quoting from the section for `saveMany()`:

> Note that we are passing numerical indices instead of usual $data
>   containing the Article key. When saving multiple records of same model
>   the records arrays should be just numerically indexed without the
>   model key.

So instead of `$data` pass `$data['Qset']` to saveAll()/saveMany().

Also `Controller::referer()` is not a static method use `$this->referer()`

Comment: Ok. I'll give that a try in the controller. Any idea why the form helper isn't creating all the inputs correctly?

Comment: The form is still not working after that modification, but it may just be because the view isn't sending the data properly. Clearly something is incorrect because only some of the input fields populate with the correct values.

Comment: Well you have only shown any code how you are populating `$this->request->data` for the admin_edit view. How your inputs are populated will depend on that.

Comment: I figured out my mistake with form inputs (see update3 above). I can now get the values to appear correctly. But now the controller still isn't working even after changing to $data['Qset'] in the controller

Comment: Show the output of `debug($data['Qset'])` in your controller before passing to save.